# How to change Text's contentDescription on JetpackCompose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, talkback, android-jetpack-compose-text

How can I change the default Text content description to be read on TalkBack on Jetpack Compose to any text that I want ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As described in the  [accessibility documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility#semantics) you can use the **`semantics`** modifier.
You can use the **`contentDescription`** semantic property to set a custom content description:

```
Text("First text", modifier = Modifier.semantics {
    this.contentDescription = "Custom content description" }
)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much!